# Possible for multiple nonpersistent ESX guests to use a single master virtual disk?

Tags: vmware-esx

I'm in the process of putting together a VDI solution for some managed desktops using ESX.  I know that I could create a VM template and just create new guests from that template.  But if I understand things correctly, that would essentially make a copy of the template's virtual disk for each guest.  So my total disk space need would roughly be the size of the template disk multipled by the total number of guests I intend to create.

However, all of these guests are going to be identical.  They'll also be set to Nonpersistent so that changes will be reverted automatically when users disconnect.  I'm wondering if it's possible to instead have all of the guests use the template disk simultaneously while keeping their own "delta" disk for changes until it's reverted.

It seems like it should be possible since no one needs to write to the master disk.  Disk performance might even be better since the common OS bits on the vDisk would be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now available via the linked clone feature.

Answer (score 0):

Usually VMware View is the soution to VDI.